# Bootstrap - how to always float left a column and keep size fixed when browser is resized

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the below html, i'm using bootstrap to create two columns.  the problem i'm having is that when the browser is re-sized, the padding/margin between the columns increases and decreases.  additionally, the size of the 2nd column (div id=filterHeading) also increases or decreases.  I would like for this 2nd column to always float left and for the size to remain fixed.  Is there a 'boostrapable' way to do this?

```
<div style="height:100%; width:100%; padding-right:15px" class="panel-body">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4 nopadding">
            <div>
                <label for="cmbDataSets">Select Data Set:</label>
                <select id="cmbDataSets" data-bind="options: dataSets, optionsText:'descr', value:selectedDataSet, optionsCaption:'Choose'" class=" form-control"></select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="cmbInstruments">Select Data Item:</label>
                <select id="cmbInstruments" data-bind="options: instruments, optionsText:'instrument', value:selectedInstrument, optionsCaption:'Choose'" class=" form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default nopadding">
                <div id="filterHeading" class="panel-heading minpadding"><b>Show Only:</b></div>
                <div id="optDataCats" data-bind="foreach: dataCategories" class="panel-body" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {value:category}, checked: selectedDataCategories"><span data-bind="text:descr" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>
    <table id="gridCot"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

I know i can probably solve this using tables, which i tempted to do and simply use bootstrap for the control look and feel rather than layout.  But i figure before going there, i would like to know if this can easily be done w/ bootstrap.

thanks

Comment: make a fiddle for this. You need "pull-left" class from bootstrap css

Comment: You will need custom CSS to do this, bootstrap does not support a fixed width column

Comment: Do you have a `container` `div` defined? Additionally, I think, but am not sure, that the size of the columns should add to 12 in a row.

Comment: yes, i'm using container-fluid